# Testing an AJAX dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two AJAX dropdowns, the first shows CountryObjs, and the second show the CityObjs belonging to that CountryObj. Selecting a different CountryObjs sends an AJAX request that updates the CityObjs for the new CountryObj. I'd like a simple test that passes a CountryObj and checks the CityObjs that are returned.

routes.rb

```
match '/update_cities', to: 'guides#update_cities', via: 'get'
```

Guide belongs_to CityObj and CountryObj, and they in turn has_many Guides.

guides_controller.rb

```
def update_cities
    @cities = CityObj.where("country_obj_id = ?", 
                             params[:country_obj_id]).order(:name)
                             debugger
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
end
```

I'm still confused by testing in Rails. I'm not using rspec. Looking at my other tests that get :index and get :show, it seems like I should be able to do something like the following to pass a CountryObj and get into the update_cities method:

```
test "ajax dropdown" do
    get :update_cities, city_obj: CityObj.last
end
```

But that gives an error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat Exception: ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) request using GET you should try like this

`test "ajax dropdown" do
 xhr :get, :update_cities, city_obj: CityObj.last
end`